# Regex: every group is optional, at least one must exist, after that anything else is allowed

Tags: regex, option-type

This is a situation almost like in [Regex: individually optional capture groups, but collectively at least one must exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494174/regex-individually-optional-capture-groups-but-collectively-at-least-one-must), but with a twist which makes the solution from there impossible to use - the old solution relies on the end of string coming after the optional groups.

I am checking whether the data we are getting as input from an outside source is valid. There are three elements, let's call them T, N and M, of which at least one has to be present at the beginning of the string. It is possible that two or all three are present. The order is prescribed. And after my required element(s) have appeared, anything else may also appear, but not one of the original elements (variation: the optional tail that comes afterwards has to start with a character from a defined group, and that group does not include the T, N or M characters). There can be whitespace before the elements, between the elements, and afterwards.

(I am calling them "elements" and each of them is a substring for which I have a valid regex, which I will plug as a group - but for the example here, I will just use the characters T, N and M as placeholders).

Going by the other question, I tried using a negative lookahead, but the problem is that I can't specify the end of the string.

> (?!$)(T?)(N?)(M?)$

This doesn't match cases like `TNL1` which are valid (I have a T and N at the beginning, so I don't care if an L1 comes afterwards)

> (?!$)(T?)(N?)(M?)

This matches anything except an empty string, such as `L1` only.

Some valid test cases are: `T`, `N`, `M`, `TM`, `T N`, `TM and something else`. Some invalid test cases are: `only other stuff`, `MNT`, `other beginning, then TNM`, ``

What would be a proper regex to check which of my strings are valid?

Comment: Why not an `OR` construction using pipe symbol? > `^(T|N|M).*$`

Comment: What is the regex flavor, BTW? Actually, your rules are unclear as you should not care what goes after `M` in `MNT`, it should be a match according to your rules.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my code is in R, I think that the regex function in it has a parameter that can choose between several flavors, but never had to write a regex so complicated that the flavor mattered.

Comment: @JvdV I believe this allows exactly one of the three at the beginning. I want to have one, or two, or all three. If I am wrong and the pipe is an inclusive OR, please write an answer about it.

Comment: Ok, I see, you have a choice between TRE, PCRE, ICU and even Tcl. I have come  up with something like `^(?=T|N|M)(T)?(N)?(M)?.*$`, but it will match `MNT`.

Comment: @RumiP. yes but as per the above comment you can then include optional groups if that's what you want to include.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like to avoid repeating the elements within the regex, 1) because each of them is moderately complicated in itself, making the whole regex hard to understand and maintain, and 2) a generic solution that works for more than 3 elements is nicer, and it gets quickly too long if we have to list every possible order.

Comment: @RumiP. You won't have to repeat much, with PCRE, you will be able to use subroutines, that will make it look neat in the end. See `^(?=(T)|(N)|(M))((?1))?((?2))?((?3))?.*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oz2E1r/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK, thanks. I do regex very rarely and didn't know that it has subroutines, that's very interesting to know. I still cannot construct a full solution with these hints, if you have one, I would be very grateful if you post it.

Comment: There is a contradiction in “And after my required element(s) have appeared, anything else may also appear.” and calling `MNT` invalid. It starts with a required element, `M`, followed by “anything else”, i.e. `NT`. It seems like the remainder has restrictions which are not well described.

Comment: @Holger you are right, the remainder does have restrictions, which make the question underdefined. I was wary of including the formal restrictions into my code, since the people entering don't know the format well enough to keep them properly, and the first groups are the really important ones. But let's then say that the remainder should be anything that is not one of the already-defined groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `^(?=[ ]*[TNM])(?:[ ]*T)?(?:[ ]*N)?(?:[ ]*M)?[ ]*(?:(?>[^TNM\s])|$).*$`

or with function subsitution

```
^(?=[ ]*(?:(?&T)|(?&N)|(?&M)))(?:[ ]*(?&T))?(?:[ ]*(?&N))?(?:[ ]*(?&M))?[ ]*(?:(?>(?!(?:(?&T)|(?&N)|(?&M)|\s)).)|$).*$(?(DEFINE)(?<T>T)(?<N>N)(?<M>M))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Gafmz/1) or [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/cOTMSq/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks, this looks good. As I mentioned in the coments under the question, I would be interested in not repeating T, N and M much because they are somewhat long in reality. I tried using PCRE subroutines in your suggestion but failed, can you make a variant that uses them? https://regex101.com/r/aJCDy8/1.

Comment: Added function subsitution demo